# Best way to load page data into div with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have been doing a lot of VueJS tutorials including the `router`, `event bus`, and trying to use `fetchival` and `axios` to no avail.

The setup, I want there to be two sections. One where I have buttons and the second section would be updated with html data from html files that varies depending on the button pressed.

I have used event bus to be able to just update the second div with basic, static html
(i.e. `<p>got it</p>`) but I cannot, for the life of me, use any request to get html from another website or file and load it into the div.

I don't necessarily need anyone to build it for me, but even some guidance and direction would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are these html files yours (making this similar in approach to a tabbed interface)? Or are you like loading external websites into a box based on the button pressed?

Comment: They are mine, they reside on the same server. I tried to add the folder to the root of the app to access them with no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments above, I think you want to change your thinking from "loading html files" to "showing different parts of the Vue component."

Here's a basic example. I'm going to use Vue [single-file component syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), but it's not hard to refactor for [class-based components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="clickedShowFirst">Show First</button>
    <button @click="clickedShowSecond">Show Second</button>
    <div v-if="showingFirst">
      This is the first section!
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      This is the second section!
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        // We default to showing the first block
        showingFirst: true
      }
    }

    methods: {
      clickedShowFirst: function () {
        this.showingFirst = true
      },

      clickedShowSecond: function () {
        this.showingFirst = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You could of course make each of the `v-if` blocks components of their own that you import (which makes sense if they are complex themselves).

Or as suggested by Phillipe, you can use [vue-router](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html) and make each of those views a different page with a different URL.

One last recommendation to leave you with, I found [Jeffrey Way's Laracasts series on Vue.js](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step) amazingly helpful when I was learning. His episode titled "[Exercise #3: Tabs](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/11)" is very similar to what you're asking here.

Comment: I will definitely check out Jeffery Way's series, thank you so much! I will actually, eventually, have about 100 links on the left div and want one of the 100 pages of html loaded into the right div. It's for a users manual we are trying to make into a webapp. I think your v-html would be the best solution, as vue-router looks as if I'd have to make 100 vue-routes

Comment: The big reason you'd want to pull `vue-router` out is if you want those sections to change the url and therefore be linkable.

Comment: I see, yeah, changing the url doesn't matter to me. So, sounds like you'd go with v-html. Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You could use vue-router (https://router.vuejs.org/en/). In first section put the router-link (https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html), your buttons, in second section put the router-view (https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html).